# ***Unknown command message when using curl on mininet

Tags: curl, mininet

I am implementing a Software Defined Network using Mininet. Done so far, but I'm trying to apply an access control policy to my network.

I have a few questions,

1. Is the "curl " command supposed to work within the "mininet>" prompt? I constantly receive a "***Unknown Command:..." error when I try to use it.

Currently the only way I can manipulate the firewall is outside the running network, i.e on my browser or on the 'mininet@mininet-vm~$' workspace. please advise.

2. I believe the following command is supposed to deny communication between two network hosts (i.e h1 and h3), but it is not working on my system. please advise

curl -X POST -d '{"src-ip":"10.0.0.1", "dst-ip": "10.0.0.3", "action":"DENY"}' http://192.168.227.1:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json

I'm working on Windows 7 Home.

Thanks,

Absalom Lwande

Answer (score 0):

The 'curl' command is a shell command. To run a shell command in mininet, after the 'mininet>' prompt you must use the mininet 'sh' command.

Find documentation for this on this link: 
http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1cli_1_1CLI.html#a4df722296f69ca6f19f8fd89ea225042